# Bubblesort doesn't sort properly

Tags: java, sorting

I have some code that I've compiled and ran. It is suppose to sort the values from smallest to greatest. Can someone help me find what is going on in the code and not making it sort correctly? I get these numbers

```
-9  -3  -1  1  6  7  83  19  2  6  4  6  32  66
```

Can someone help me and tell me what is wrong with the code? Thank you!

```
int myArray[] = {1, 6, -1, 7, 83, 19, -3, 6, 2, 4, 6, 32, 66, -9};
int n = myArray.length;
myArray = doop(myArray);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}

private static int[] doop(int[] myArray) {
  int n = myArray.length;
  int swap;
  for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      int j = i;
      int min = myArray[i];
      while ((j > 0) && (myArray[j - 1] < min)) {
          myArray[j] = myArray[j - 1];
          j = j - 1;
      }
      myArray[j] = min;
  }
  return myArray;
}
```

Comment: This seems more like insertion sort rather than bubble sort.

Comment: (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: also myArray[j] = min; should be in the while

Comment: What about the (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) ?

Comment: You should just redo the code going forward

Comment: (int i = 0; i >n; i++)

Answer (score 1):

In bubble sort you have to compare the only the adjacent elements and traverse the array. Repeating this n-1 times , your array gets sorted and so correct code is:

```
private static int[] doop(int[] myArray) 
{
 int n = myArray.length;     
 for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
 {
 for(int j=n-1;j>0;j--)
 {
  if(myArray[j]<myArray[j-1])
  {
     //swapping the elements
     myArray[j]=myArray[j]^myArray[j-1];
     myArray[j-1]=myArray[j]^myArray[j-1];
     myArray[j]=myArray[j]^myArray[j-1];
  }   
 }
 }
return myArray;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int myArray[] = {1, 6, -1, 7, 83, 19, -3, 6, 2, 4, 6, 32, 66, -9};
int n = myArray.length;
myArray = doop(myArray);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
}

private static int[] doop(int[] myArray) {
int n = myArray.length;
int swap;
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int j = i;
    int min = myArray[i];
    while ((j > 0) && (myArray[j - 1] < min)) {
        myArray[j] = myArray[j - 1];
        j = j - 1;
       myArray[j] = min;
    }

}
return myArray;
}
```